# List of all swing components

Tags: java, swing

Is there any resource online that lists every single swing component, i.e., anything that can have some sort of listener attached to it.

I've looked around but a lot of the resources [like this one](http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~cs3283/ftp/Java/swingConnect/archive/what_is_arch/tool_set/tool_set.html) only show you some of them.

CellRendererPane is not a subclass of JComponent but you can still attach a [swing event listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/package-summary.html) to it. I am looking for all classes in swing that allow you to attach any one of the listeners under swing.event.

Comment: Start with the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html).

Comment: Also the API - [Package javax.swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html), specifically the class summary section.

Comment: a good list but may be not complete - http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/swing/components.shtml

Comment: You can browse the subclass hierarchy of `JComponent` from the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html)

Comment: `CellRendererPane is not a subclass of JComponent` - so look under the Component API and excluded classes found in java.awt. I doubt you will find a list. If you actually state a reason why you think this information is important, we may be able to give better advice.

Comment: I am writing a program that will allow you to attach swing.event listeners to a variable. I have to check the type of the variable to see if the listener is able to be attached to it. So I'm trying to compile a list of all classes that can have any one of the swing.event listeners attached to it

Comment: @Ogen, use reflection to get a list of the methods supported by the class.

Comment: The class type is being read as a string. I can't use reflection because you cannot parse a JButton from a string for use in reflection. Unlike a primitive where you can say, for example, Boolean.parseBoolean("false"). I don't think I can use reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The class type is being read as a string.

Maybe something like:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class ReflectionTest{

public static void main(String[] args)
    throws Exception
{
new ReflectionTest();
}

public ReflectionTest()
    throws Exception
{

//  Class thisClass = ReflectionTest.class;
    Class thisClass = Class.forName("javax.swing.JButton");
    Field[] fields = thisClass.getFields();

    for(int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Field #" + (i+1) + ": " + fields[i].getName());
    }

//  Method[] methods = thisClass.getDeclaredMethods();
    Method[] methods = thisClass.getMethods();

    for(int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Method #" + (i+1) + ": " + methods[i].getName());
    }

}

public int Scooby = 1;
public String Doo;

}
```

If this doesn't help then I don't understand the question. Why don't you provide an simple example of what you are trying to do.